# Export query result to csv in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

So i have a query that i would like to execute through a stored procedure and export the output of the query to a CSV file. So i am using the following stored procedure to do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parseCSV(
p_file_dir         VARCHAR2, -- Oracle directory name
p_file_name     VARCHAR2, -- filename
p_sql_query        VARCHAR2, -- select * from table or some such query
p_delimiter     CHAR      -- column delimiter
)
AS

l_cursor_handle  INTEGER;
l_dummy              NUMBER;
l_col_cnt          INTEGER;
l_rec_tab            DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
l_current_col      NUMBER(16);
l_current_line   VARCHAR2(2047);
l_column_value   VARCHAR2(300);
l_file_handle      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
l_print_text       VARCHAR2(100);
l_record_count   NUMBER(16) := 0;

BEGIN
   l_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_file_dir, p_file_name, 'a', 2047); 
   l_cursor_handle := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(l_cursor_handle, p_sql_query, DBMS_SQL.native);
   l_dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(l_cursor_handle);
   DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(l_cursor_handle, l_col_cnt, l_rec_tab); 
   l_current_col := l_rec_tab.FIRST;
   IF (l_current_col IS NOT NULL) THEN
      LOOP
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value, 300);
         l_print_text := l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name || p_delimiter;
         UTL_FILE.PUT (l_file_handle, l_print_text);
         l_current_col := l_rec_tab.NEXT(l_current_col);
         EXIT WHEN (l_current_col IS NULL);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle,' ');
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_handle) = 0; 

      l_current_line := '';
      FOR l_current_col IN 1..l_col_cnt LOOP
         DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value);
         l_print_text := l_column_value || p_delimiter;

         l_current_line := l_current_line || l_column_value || p_delimiter;
      END LOOP;
      l_record_count := l_record_count + 1;
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle, l_current_line);
   END LOOP;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (l_file_handle);
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_handle);
END;
/
```

The procedure when executed processes the query and then stores the result into a delimited file. For example, the output of the procedure for a regular SELECT statement will be of this form:

```
ID,ROLL_NO,RANK, 
1,123456,1620,
2,987654,1344,
```

Now herein lies my issue. As you can see each row within the output file is ending with an extra trailing `,`. Now, due to my lack of knowledge in plsql, i can't think of a modification that i can do to the procedure so that the expected output file would be of this form:

```
ID,ROLL_NO,RANK 
1,123456,1620
2,987654,1344
```

Could someone be kind enough to help out an Oracle newbie here and give me some pointers as to how i can do it? I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below where comments have been added

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parseCSV(
p_file_dir         VARCHAR2, -- Oracle directory name
p_file_name     VARCHAR2, -- filename
p_sql_query        VARCHAR2, -- select * from table or some such query
p_delimiter     CHAR      -- column delimiter
)
AS

    l_cursor_handle  INTEGER;
    l_dummy              NUMBER;
    l_col_cnt          INTEGER;
    l_rec_tab            DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    l_current_col      NUMBER(16);
    l_current_line   VARCHAR2(2047);
    l_column_value   VARCHAR2(300);
    l_file_handle      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    l_print_text       VARCHAR2(100);
    l_record_count   NUMBER(16) := 0;

    BEGIN
       l_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_file_dir, p_file_name, 'a', 2047); 
       l_cursor_handle := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
       DBMS_SQL.PARSE(l_cursor_handle, p_sql_query, DBMS_SQL.native);
       l_dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(l_cursor_handle);
       DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(l_cursor_handle, l_col_cnt, l_rec_tab); 
       l_current_col := l_rec_tab.FIRST;
       IF (l_current_col IS NOT NULL) THEN
          LOOP
             DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value, 300);

             l_print_text := l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name || 
             p_delimiter;
             l_current_col := l_rec_tab.NEXT(l_current_col);
             IF l_current_col IS NULL/*handling for last delimiter for 
            column */
             THEN
             l_print_text:=substr(l_print_text,-1);
             END IF;
             UTL_FILE.PUT (l_file_handle, l_print_text);
             EXIT WHEN (l_current_col IS NULL);
          END LOOP;
       END IF;
       UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle,' ');
       LOOP
          EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_handle) = 0; 

          l_current_line := '';
          FOR l_current_col IN 1..l_col_cnt LOOP
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value);
             l_print_text := l_column_value || p_delimiter;
             IF l_current_col =l_col_cnt
             then
             l_current_line := l_current_line || l_column_value;
             ELSE
             l_current_line := l_current_line || l_column_value || 
             p_delimiter;
             END IF;
          END LOOP;
          l_record_count := l_record_count + 1;
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle, l_current_line);
       END LOOP;
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (l_file_handle);
       DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_handle);
    END;
```

Comment: Hi, could you please showcase how the entire procedure will look like? Kindly bear with me, i'm just an oracle newbie

Comment: hi ,i have added the same

Comment: In the output file header is fine, but none of the values are coming. Looks like this:`ID,MSISDN,RECHARGE_DATE,RECHARGE_AMOUNT -- in next line
, -- next line
, -- next line
, -- next line
`

Comment: Coud you please take a look?

Comment: Check if the table has data

Comment: Yes, it has data. When i remove `l_current_line:=substr(l_current_line,-1);` script gives output with trailing , for each records.

Comment: Hi ,i have made necessary changes please check now

Comment: Hi i am getting error like this  ORA-29280: invalid directory object
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "LEAP.PARSECSV", line 21

Comment: what is the value of p_file_dir you are passing ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parseCSV(
p_file_dir         VARCHAR2, -- Oracle directory name
p_file_name     VARCHAR2, -- filename
p_sql_query        VARCHAR2, -- select * from table or some such query
p_delimiter     CHAR      -- column delimiter
)
AS

l_cursor_handle  INTEGER;
l_dummy              NUMBER;
l_col_cnt          INTEGER;
l_rec_tab            DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
l_current_col      NUMBER(16);
l_current_line   VARCHAR2(2047);
l_column_value   VARCHAR2(300);
l_file_handle      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
l_print_text       VARCHAR2(100);
l_record_count   NUMBER(16) := 0;

BEGIN
   l_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_file_dir, p_file_name, 'a', 2047);
   l_cursor_handle := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(l_cursor_handle, p_sql_query, DBMS_SQL.native);
   l_dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(l_cursor_handle);
   DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(l_cursor_handle, l_col_cnt, l_rec_tab);
   l_current_col := l_rec_tab.FIRST;
   IF (l_current_col IS NOT NULL) THEN
      LOOP
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value, 300);
         IF l_print_text IS NOT NULL THEN
           l_print_text := l_print_text || p_delimiter;
         END IF;
         l_print_text := l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name;
         UTL_FILE.PUT (l_file_handle, l_print_text);
         l_current_col := l_rec_tab.NEXT(l_current_col);
         EXIT WHEN (l_current_col IS NULL);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle,' ');
   l_print_text := NULL;
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_handle) = 0;

      l_current_line := '';
      FOR l_current_col IN 1..l_col_cnt LOOP
         DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value);
         IF l_print_text IS NOT NULL THEN
           l_print_text := l_print_text || p_delimiter;
         END IF;

         l_print_text := l_column_value;

      END LOOP;
      l_record_count := l_record_count + 1;
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle, l_print_text );
   END LOOP;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (l_file_handle);
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_handle);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but the output file is not generated the correct way. File looks something like this:`IDROLL_NORANK 
1
123456
1620
2
987654
1344`. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd say procedure which exports CSV file should be named `createCSV`, `makeCSV` or something similar, but never `parseCSV`.

Next, I'm not sure that this application design in best. Usually database should worry of data while external client thinking about medias, formats and so on.

At last, for elimination of trailing delimiter you should use something like this:

```
...
p_delimiter     CHAR      -- column delimiter
)
AS

l_delimiter     varchar2(1 char);

...

BEGIN
   ....
   l_current_col := l_rec_tab.FIRST;
   l_delimiter := '';
   ....
         l_print_text := l_delimiter || l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name;
         l_delimiter := p_delimiter;
   ....
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things.  The first is to update your call to UTL_FILE.put so you conditionally add the delimiter (example below for the header record but the same can be applied to the data) :

```
     IF l_current_col < l_rec_tab.LAST THEN
       l_print_text := l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name || p_delimiter;
     ELSE
       l_print_text := l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name ;
     END IF ;
     UTL_FILE.PUT (l_file_handle, l_print_text);
```

The second approach would be to build up a string with a complete row of data and then manipulate that string before you call UTL FILE (in this case I am assuming l_print_text is long enough for a row of data) :

```
   IF (l_current_col IS NOT NULL) THEN
      LOOP
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_handle, l_current_col, l_column_value, 300);
         --append to variable
         l_print_text := l_print_text||l_rec_tab(l_current_col).col_name || p_delimiter;
         l_current_col := l_rec_tab.NEXT(l_current_col);
         EXIT WHEN (l_current_col IS NULL);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
   --trim trailing delimiter
   l_print_text := TRIM(TRAILING p_delimiter FROM l_print_text) ;
   --send whole line to file
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (l_file_handle,l_print_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a little. User this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PARSECSV
(
  P_FILE_DIR  VARCHAR2, -- Oracle directory name
  P_FILE_NAME VARCHAR2, -- filename
  P_SQL_QUERY VARCHAR2, -- select * from table or some such query
  P_DELIMITER CHAR -- column delimiter
) IS

  L_CURSOR_HANDLE INTEGER;
  L_DUMMY         NUMBER;
  L_COL_CNT       INTEGER;
  L_REC_TAB       DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  L_COLUMN_VALUE  VARCHAR2(300);
  L_FILE_HANDLE   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  L_PRINT_TEXT    CLOB;

BEGIN
  L_FILE_HANDLE   := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(P_FILE_DIR,
                                    P_FILE_NAME,
                                    'a',
                                    2047);
  L_CURSOR_HANDLE := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(L_CURSOR_HANDLE,
                 P_SQL_QUERY,
                 DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(L_CURSOR_HANDLE,
                            L_COL_CNT,
                            L_REC_TAB);

  FOR L_CURRENT_COL IN 1 .. L_COL_CNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(L_CURSOR_HANDLE,
                           L_CURRENT_COL,
                           L_COLUMN_VALUE,
                           300);

    IF L_PRINT_TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN
      L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || P_DELIMITER;
    END IF;
    L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || L_REC_TAB(L_CURRENT_COL).COL_NAME;
  END LOOP;
  L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || CHR(10) || CHR(13);
  UTL_FILE.PUT(L_FILE_HANDLE,
               L_PRINT_TEXT);

  L_PRINT_TEXT := NULL;
  L_DUMMY      := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(L_CURSOR_HANDLE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_DUMMY);

  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(L_CURSOR_HANDLE) = 0;

    FOR L_CURRENT_COL IN 1 .. L_COL_CNT
    LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CURSOR_HANDLE,
                            L_CURRENT_COL,
                            L_COLUMN_VALUE);
      IF L_PRINT_TEXT IS NOT NULL THEN
        L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || P_DELIMITER;
      END IF;

      L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || L_COLUMN_VALUE;

    END LOOP;
    L_PRINT_TEXT := L_PRINT_TEXT || CHR(10) || CHR(13);
    UTL_FILE.PUT(L_FILE_HANDLE,
                 L_PRINT_TEXT);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(L_FILE_HANDLE);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(L_CURSOR_HANDLE);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a directory in the database and provide the read, write access to that directory.

To create a directory:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY alias AS 'pathname';
```

To Grant Read,Write:

```
GRANT read,write ON DIRECTORY alias TO {user | role | PUBLIC};
```

After that use below stored procedure to get the output of SQL query in any file format.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CSV_EXPORT AS
  CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT * from table_name;

  v_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'FILES1',
                           filename     => 'csv_exp.txt',
                           open_mode    => 'w',
                           max_linesize => 32767);
  FOR cur_rec IN c_data LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file,
                      cur_rec.column1    || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.column2 );
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    RAISE;
END;
```

To run the stored procedure:

```
EXEC CSV_EXPORT;
```

here in code FILES1 is directory name.